# How to efficiently parse large list data during scraping with python?

Tags: python, list, numpy, parsing, screen-scraping

I am currently working on a data scraping project, which requires me to load and save my data in every loop. You might wonder why I would do that? Well, before I scraped without loading and saving my data in between every loop and lost all my data if the script crashed anywhere before the last iteration (which happened every time due to timeout, weird URL or anything you can imagine).

All in all the method applied right now works fine, but after some 20k iterations my storage files increase to a length of ~90mb resulting in the script becoming slower and slower, forcing me to create a new data saving file. The code below shows the basic functioning of my script.

```
import numpy as np

#List with URLS to scrape (220k URLS)
URLS = np.load("/some_directory/URLS.npy").tolist()

#Already checked URLS
Checked_URLS=np.load("/some_directory/checked_URLS.npy").tolist()

#Perform scraping and add new URL to checked list
for i in URLS:
    if i not in Checked_URLS:
        Checked_already.append(i)
        np.save("some_directory/checked_URLS.npy", Checked_already)
        NEW_DATA=Bunch_of_scraping_code

        #Load numpy list with data collected from previous URLS
        #Append new scraping data and save list
        FOUND_DATA=np.load("/some_directory/FOUND_DATA.npy", allow_pickle=True).tolist()
        FOUND_DATA.append(NEW_DATA)
        np.save("some_directory/FOUND_DATA.npy", LOT_DATA)
```

I am sure there must be a more pythonic way, in which it is not required to load the entire lists into python every loop? Or perhaps another way which does not require writing at all? I write my lists to .npy because, as far as I am aware, this is the most efficient way to parse large list files.

I have tried to save my data directly into pandas but this made everything much worse and slower. All help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think that a much more efficient approach would be to wrap the code that might crash with `try/except` and log the problematic urls for further investigation instead of repeating the same operations over and over again:

```
for url in URLS:
    try:
        FOUND_DATA=np.load("/some_directory/FOUND_DATA.npy", allow_pickle=True).tolist()
        FOUND_DATA.append(NEW_DATA)
    except Exception as ex:
        # for any reason the code crashes, the following message will be printed and the loop will continue
        print(f"Failed to process url: {url})
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not think this solves my problem. It is true I could wrap the problematic part of code in a try-except statement, however if my internet times out, access to the page gets denied or the shell crashes due to memory errors etc, the found data and searched URLs would be either partly corrupted or gone. I prefer that in these kind of cases the script terminates. Therefore it is preferred to write out the correct data in every loop or before an error occurs. .

Comment: IMHO the most significant risk in your case is unresponsive url and in that case a simple error handling strategy will protect your code. Regarding the other scenarios, I don't think you should protect yourself from within the code but with running on the right environment. For example, running on a small aws server will ensure a stable connectivity. Same thing regarding the memory issues - if you append to your file after each iteration, your memory fingerprint should be low.